# Determine the number of hosts from IP address prefix

Tags: cisco, ipv4, network-core

Is it possible to quickly determine the number of hosts by giving only the IP prefix such as /24 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A 24 bit mask is providing 2 at the power of 8 hosts. It's the difference betwen your network mask and the full 32 bit mask. Like a /30 has:
32-30 = 2; 2 at power of 2 equals 4.